# UDP functionality for communication between 2 ports/sockets?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

What purpose is UDP for..if it delivers packets without any order (and given the fact that packets may get lost on the way or sent to other network).

Answer (score 1):

UDP as many very usefull use cases.

Just a few off the top of my head:

**1/ Your payloads are small (will hold in a single "packet") and you want to go fast.** That's why DNS uses UDP when the data size does exceeds 512 bytes (99% of the cases?):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Protocol_transport

And you do hundreds of DNS requests every day. How many TCP 3-way handshakes and connection tear-down saved by this? How may petabytes or network load saved on "the internet"? I'd say that's quite useful!

**2/ You do not know who you are talking too, or even if someone is listening or wishing to reply.** In other words, you cannot or do not want for sure to establish an actual connection, like TCP would do. There may not be a TCP service listening for you. For example, the SSDP protocol from UPnP uses UDP to discover devices/services:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol

With UDP tough, you can send your data "in the wild" even if nobody is listening to you. Which leads me to point 3...

**3/ You want to talk to multiple hosts, or even "everyone". That's multicasting and broadcasting**, and it's *very* easy to do in UDP. The SSDP mentioned above is an example of such case. On the other hand, if you want to do multicast or broadcast on TCP, that becomes *very* tricky from the start. You'll have to subscribe to multicast group and blablabla. A multicast daemon may help (ex: https://github.com/troglobit/smcroute), but it's really way more difficult in TCP than with UDP.

**4/ Your data is realtime,** if the target is missing it there's no point for it to ask for a "please send it again, I did not get it and/or not in the correct order". That's too late, sorry. The receiver better forget it, go on and try to catch-up. A typical use case here can be live audio/video (telephony conversations, real time video streaming). There's no point for the receiver to try to get old, expired data again and again in case of TCP missed segment(s). You can only accumulate network data debt doing this. Better forget it and move on to the new, real-time data that keep coming in. *You cannot "pause" real-time incoming data.* If you want *actual* real-time, not *pseudo* real-time like you get in your web browser.

And I'm sure other posters will find many use-cases for UDP.

So UDP is very, VERY useful. You use it daily without noticing it. The networking world would be a pitiful place without it. You would really miss it. The "TCP/IP" should really be renamed "TCP-UDP/IP".

This was my advocacy for the unfairly despised but Oh-so-useful UDP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, use UDP in applications where speed is more critical than reliability. For example, it may be better to use UDP in an application sending data from a fast acquisition where it is acceptable to lose some data points. You can also use UDP to broadcast/multicast to any/many machine(s) listening to the server.

Applications may want finer control over the performance characteristics or the reliability of their communications. For this, the operating system exposes IP’s “best-effort datagrams” to the application for it to do whatever it wants with them.

To do this, the OS provides UDP — the “user” datagram protocol. It’s just like IP, in that the service is best-effort datagrams, but instead of delivering those datagrams “to a computer,” there’s an added layer of addressing that says which application is interested in them (and like TCP, UDP does this with a port number).

Applications can run whatever they want on top of UDP — anything that runs on best-effort datagrams. There are lots of protocols you can run on top of that abstraction.

In general:

TCP is for high-reliability data transmissions

UDP is for low-overhead transmissions